# Uploading a file as multipart/form-data using retrofit gives 400 errorcode

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, multipartform-data

Trying to upload an image as multipart/form-data as below is the formation of the form-data.

This is what the spring boot method takes as parameter. This method is in a separate spring boot application which saves the file to the database.

```
public String uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,@RequestParam("desc") String desc,@RequestParam("uploadId") String uploadId ) {...}
```

I get errorcode 400(bad request) and the errorBody gives empty string. I am not able to get what i am doing wrong.
The below code is to form the form-data request

```
try {
            RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), file);
            MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), reqFile);

            String descStr = file.getName();
            RequestBody desc = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), descStr);

            String uploadIdStr = receiptId;
            RequestBody uploadId = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), uploadIdStr);

            imgRequest = RetrofitHelper.uploadImage(ApplicationConstants.BEARER + " " + StringBox.getInstance(mActivity).getStringPreference(ApplicationConstants.ACCESS_TOKEN), body, desc, uploadId);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(tag, e.getMessage());
        }


        imgRequest.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {...}
```

The retrofit API is configured as such

```
@Multipart
    @POST("/upload")
    Call<ResponseBody> uploadImage(@Header("Content-Type") String type,
                                   @Header("Authorization") String authorization,
                                   @Part MultipartBody.Part file,
                                   @Part("desc") RequestBody req,
                                   @Part("uploadId") RequestBody uploadId);
```

```
public static Call<ResponseBody> uploadImage(String accessToken, MultipartBody.Part body, RequestBody desc, RequestBody req) {
        RetrofitAPI mApi = RetrofitClient.getInstance().create(RetrofitAPI.class);

        Call<ResponseBody> uploadImage = mApi.uploadImage("multipart/form-data; boundary=" + System.currentTimeMillis(), accessToken, body, desc, req);

        return uploadImage;
    }
```

Below is the response header

```
Date: Wed, 23 Sep 2020 07:13:25 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close
```

Answer (score 0):

Was searching around for a relevant problem I faced, here are my findings.
[image]

---

1. Upload image in parts then

   ```
   @Multipart
   @POST("api/uploadpic")
   fun submitDP(@Part body: MultipartBody.Part): Call<UploadImageResponse>
   ```

---

2. Abstain from adding the headers manually as the @Multipart annotation would take care of it. When I need to add the authorization header then I prefer the interceptors

   ```
           class OAuthInterceptor(private val tokenType: String, private val 
            accessToken: 
            String) :
            Interceptor {
            override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): okhttp3.Response {
            var request = chain.request()
            //do not pass content length to GET requests
            if(!request.method().equals("GET"))
            request = request.newBuilder()
           .header("Authorization", "$tokenType $accessToken")
           .header("Content-Length", request.body()?.contentLength().toString())
           .header("Host", "your.domain.com") //if this is not added then add 
            HostnameVerifier to interceptor
           .header("Accept", "application/json")
           .build()
       else
           request = request.newBuilder()
               .header("Authorization", "$tokenType $accessToken")
               .header("Host", "your.domain.com")
               .header("Accept", "application/json")
               .build()
       return chain.proceed(request)
   }
   ```

   }

---

3. then create the part, using form-data as content

   ```
   val requestFile: RequestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpg"), 
   bytes)
   val body: MultipartBody.Part = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("your_key", 
   "image", requestFile)
   ```